# Tensorflow gradients are 0, weights are not updating

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision, deep-learning

I'm trying to learn TensorFlow after using Keras for a while, and I'm trying to build a ConvNet for CIFAR-10 classification. However, I think I misunderstand something in TensorFlow API, since the weights are not updating even in 1-layer net model.

The code for the model is as follows:

```
num_epochs = 10 
batch_size = 64

# Shape of mu and std is correct: (1, 32, 32, 3)
mu = np.mean(X_train, axis=0, keepdims=True)
sigma = np.std(X_train, axis=0, keepdims=True)

# Placeholders for data & normalization
# (normalisation does not help)
data = tf.placeholder(np.float32, shape=(None, 32, 32, 3), name='data')
labels = tf.placeholder(np.int32, shape=(None,), name='labels')
data = (data - mu) / sigma

# flatten
flat = tf.reshape(data, shape=(-1, 32 * 32 * 3))
dense1 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=flat, units=10)
predictions = tf.nn.softmax(dense1)

onehot_labels = tf.one_hot(indices=labels, depth=10)

# Tried sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits as well
loss = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(onehot_labels=onehot_labels, logits=predictions)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(loss)

# Learning rate does not matter as the weights are not updating!
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01).minimize(loss)
loss_history = []

with tf.Session() as session:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    tf.local_variables_initializer().run()

    for epochs in range(10):
        print("Epoch:", epochs)
        # Load tiny batches-
        for batch in iterate_minibatches(X_train.astype(np.float32)[:10], y_train[:10], 5):
            inputs, target = batch
            feed_dict = {data: inputs, labels: target}
            loss_val, _ = session.run([loss, optimizer], feed_dict=feed_dict)
            grads = tf.reduce_sum(tf.gradients(loss, dense1)[0])
            grads = session.run(grads, {data: inputs, labels: target})
            print("Loss:", loss_val, "Grads:", grads)
```

The code produces the following output:

```
Epoch: 0
Loss: 2.46115 Grads: -1.02031e-17
Loss: 2.46041 Grads: 0.0
Epoch: 1
Loss: 2.46115 Grads: 0.0
Loss: 2.26115 Grads: 0.0
Epoch: 2
Loss: 2.46115 Grads: 0.0
Loss: 2.26115 Grads: 0.0
Epoch: 3
Loss: 2.46115 Grads: 0.0
Loss: 2.26115 Grads: 0.0
Epoch: 4
Loss: 2.46115 Grads: 0.0
Loss: 2.26115 Grads: 0.0
Epoch: 5
Loss: 2.46115 Grads: 0.0
Loss: 2.26115 Grads: 0.0
Epoch: 6
Loss: 2.46115 Grads: 0.0
Loss: 2.26115 Grads: 0.0
Epoch: 7
Loss: 2.46115 Grads: 0.0
Loss: 2.26115 Grads: 0.0
Epoch: 8
Loss: 2.46115 Grads: 0.0
Loss: 2.26115 Grads: 0.0
Epoch: 9
Loss: 2.46115 Grads: 0.0
Loss: 2.26115 Grads: 0.0
```

It looks like the model **probably resets** its weights somehow or stops learning completely.
I have also tried sparse softmax crossentropy loss, but nothing helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are applying softmax two times to the output, once in `tf.nn.softmax` and again when you apply `softmax_cross_entropy`. This probably destroys any learning capability in the network.